# Can not close Realm instance in ViewModel connected with Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, viewmodel

I have **single activity app** and I have `SharedViewModel` attached to it, its main purpose is to be used for inner communication between fragments, etc. I also use **Realm** as storage solution. This viewModel as well as the others viewModels extends BaseViewModel.

```kotlin
open class BaseViewModel(): ViewModel() {

    val  realm: Realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        realm.close()
        Log.d("BVM", "realm is ${ if (realm.isClosed) "closed." else "not closed.  Opened connections: ${Realm.getLocalInstanceCount(Realm.getDefaultConfiguration()!!)}"}")
    }
}
```

We are all familiar with this picture [image]

Since `SharedViewModel`'s lyfecycle depends on lifecycle of activity's lifecycle, `onCleared()` method of this viewModel will be called not after `onDestroy` call of activity, but when activity is finished. It is not the same thing. As a result of that, when I leave my app, one Realm connection stays open, because activity is not in the **Finished** state. All other viewmodels connected from fragments had called their own `onCleared()` methods and their Realm's connections are closed.

What is the best and cleanest way to handle this?

I have a workaround in which I call viewModel's `onCleared()` manually in `onDestroy` method of activity and it's working, but that solution is rubbish.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `when I leave my app, one Realm connection stays open, because activity is not in the Finished state.` that's a bug in your code, considering `onCleared()` is called when you leave the app (finish the Activity).

Comment: You should share **live data** across multiple fragments using shared `ViewModel` but for your Realm connections *(Realm related objects)*, I would recommend to use `ViewModel` that's attached to each fragments individually.

Comment: @JeelVankhede, you are right, but this SharedViewModel alsohas some livedata which activity uses and also other fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of fact, @EpicPandaForce was right, the bug was in ViewModel's creation. I used **Dagger 2** for injection of `ViewModelFactory` which looks like this:

```kotlin
@Singleton
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
        private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        val creator = creators[modelClass] ?: creators.entries.firstOrNull {
            modelClass.isAssignableFrom(it.key)
        }?.value ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class $modelClass")
        try {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return creator.get() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }
}
```

and `ViewModel`s provided by this factory were not bound to lifecycle of any activity and fragment. When I changed the creation of ViewModel as:

```kotlin
sharedViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
```

after `OnDestroy()` of activity, `onCleared()` get called.

Thanks, guys!